# Java - Get the new day of the week

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList which contains every day of the week. The function takes two arguments: the current day of the week and an integer value to increment the number of days by.

For example, if the current day is Monday and the integer value is 3, it should return Thursday.

It also needs to be able to "loop around", so if the current day is Sunday and the value is 2, it should return Tuesday.

Below is what I have so far, it only returns the currentDay. I'm really new to Java so any assistance would be great.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DaysOfWeek {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calcDay("Tue", 2));
    }

    public static String calcDay(String currentDay, int incrementDays) {

        ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();

        days.add(0,"mon");
        days.add(1,"tue");
        days.add(2,"wed");
        days.add(3,"thu");
        days.add(4,"fri");
        days.add(5,"sat");
        days.add(6,"sun");

        if((days.contains(currentDay.toLowerCase())) && ((incrementDays >= 0) && (incrementDays <= 500))) {

           for(int i = days.indexOf(currentDay.toLowerCase()); i < incrementDays+1; i++) {
                String newDay = days.get(i);
                return newDay;
            }
        } return "Invalid";
    }
}
```

Comment: "For example, if the current day is Monday and the integer value is 3, it should return Wednesday." Shouldn't be Thursday?

Comment: @deHaar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-

Comment: @Bentaye Thanks, just forgot about specifying an index on `add`... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the modulo operator.

```
 public static String calcDay(String currentDay, int incrementDays) {

    ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();

    days.add(0,"mon");
    days.add(1,"tue");
    days.add(2,"wed");
    days.add(3,"thu");
    days.add(4,"fri");
    days.add(5,"sat");
    days.add(6,"sun");

    int currentIndex = days.indexOf(currentDay.toLowerCase());
    int newDayIndex = (currentIndex + incrementDays) % 7;
    return days.get(newDayIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could change `String newDay = days.get(i);` to:

`String newDay = days.get((i+incrementDays) % 7);`

This would loop around to the beginning of the week. You pass in the increment but you forgot to use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or higher and you want to find out the day of week based on today plus some days, use `java.time` and do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDayOfWeek(3));
}

public static String getDayOfWeek(int daysAhead) {
    // get the date of today
    return LocalDate.now()
            // add the given amount of days
            .plusDays(daysAhead)
            // obtain the day of week the future date has
            .getDayOfWeek()
            // and get the name it has in a specific locale as String
            .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.US);
}
```

the output is

```
Saturday
```